# reporting services 2005 instance

Tags: reporting-services

Greetings, I have Reporting Services Installed on my computer. It was installed previously by other developer. However I cannot access reporting services instance on my localhost. When I open Reporting Services Configuration the error returned is: **no report servers were found on the specified machine**
How can I add/restore this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google search first result -

http://blogs.msdn.com/dszabo/archive/2007/04/10/quot-no-report-servers-were-found-on-the-specified-machine-quot.aspx